# NTRU BouncyCastle

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am developing a Java application and I want to add a special encryption method - NTRU. Before that I used symmetric and asymmetric methods supplied by the bouncycastle provider however now I can't understand how works Post-Quantum algorithms in bouncycastle due to lack of any information on the network. Please help me implement NTRU text encryption code.

I tried using the light-weight API but it didn't work, my code refuses to do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complete running example for NTRU, it is not a general encryption algorithm but a key exchange algorithm (KEM). To get this to work you need an actual Bouncy Castle lib available (I tested with BC verson 1.71 and 1.72).

It is taken from my Android app to test some Post Quantum Algorithms (PQC) with complete code here: https://github.com/MichaelsPlayground/PostQuantumCryptographyBc172

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.SecretKeyWithEncapsulation;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.spec.KEMExtractSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.spec.KEMGenerateSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastlePQCProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.legacy.crypto.ntru.NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.legacy.crypto.ntru.NTRUEncryptionKeyPairGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.legacy.crypto.ntru.NTRUEncryptionParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.legacy.crypto.ntru.NTRUEncryptionPrivateKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.legacy.crypto.ntru.NTRUEncryptionPublicKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.legacy.crypto.ntru.NTRUEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Arrays;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;

public class PqcNtruKem {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        // we do need the regular Bouncy Castle file that includes the PQC provider
        // get Bouncy Castle here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on
        // tested with BC version 1.71
        if (Security.getProvider("BCPQC") == null) {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastlePQCProvider());
        }
        System.out.println("PQC NTRU kem");

        System.out.println("\n************************************\n" +
                "* # # SERIOUS SECURITY WARNING # # *\n" +
                "* This program is a CONCEPT STUDY  *\n" +
                "* for the algorithm                *\n" +
                "* NTRU [key exchange mechanism]    *\n" +
                "* The program is using an          *\n" +
                "* parameter set that I cannot      *\n" +
                "* check for the correctness of the *\n" +
                "* output and other details         *\n" +
                "*                                  *\n" +
                "*    DO NOT USE THE PROGRAM IN     *\n" +
                "*    ANY PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT    *\n" +
                "************************************");

        // as there are 7 parameter sets available the program runs all of them
        NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters[] ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameterSets = {
                NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters.EES1087EP2,
                NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters.EES1171EP1,
                NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters.EES1499EP1,
                NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters.APR2011_439,
                NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters.APR2011_439_FAST,
                NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters.APR2011_743,
                NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters.APR2011_743_FAST,
        };
        // short name of the parameters for the summary print out
        String[] ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameterNames = {
                "EES1087EP2",
                "EES1171EP1",
                "EES1499EP1",
                "APR2011_439",
                "APR2011_439_FAST",
                "APR2011_743",
                "APR2011_743_FAST"
        };

        // statistics
        int nrOfSpecs = ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameterSets.length;
        String[] parameterSpecName = new String[nrOfSpecs];
        int[] privateKeyLength = new int[nrOfSpecs];
        int[] publicKeyLength = new int[nrOfSpecs];
        int[] encryptedKeyLength = new int[nrOfSpecs];
        boolean[] encryptionKeysEquals = new boolean[nrOfSpecs];

        // data to encrypt is usually a 32 bytes long (randomly generated) AES key
        String keyToEncryptString = "1234567890ABCDEF1122334455667788";
        byte[] keyToEncrypt = keyToEncryptString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfSpecs; i++) {
            // generation of the NTRU key pair
            NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters = ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameterSets[i];
            String ntruParameterSpecName = ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameterNames[i];
            parameterSpecName[i] = ntruParameterSpecName;
            System.out.println("\nNTRU KEM with parameterset " + ntruParameterSpecName);
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = generateNtruKeyPair(ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters);

            // get private and public key
            AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
            AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

            // storing the key as byte array
            byte[] privateKeyByte = ((NTRUEncryptionPrivateKeyParameters) privateKey).getEncoded();
            byte[] publicKeyByte = ((NTRUEncryptionPublicKeyParameters) publicKey).getEncoded();
            System.out.println("\ngenerated private key length: " + privateKeyByte.length);
            System.out.println("generated public key length:  " + publicKeyByte.length);
            privateKeyLength[i] = privateKeyByte.length;
            publicKeyLength[i] = publicKeyByte.length;

            // generate the keys from a byte array
            NTRUEncryptionPrivateKeyParameters privateKeyLoad = getNtruPrivateKeyFromEncoded(privateKeyByte, ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters);
            NTRUEncryptionPublicKeyParameters publicKeyLoad = getNtruPublicKeyFromEncoded(publicKeyByte, ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters);

            // generate the encryption key and the encapsulated key
            System.out.println("\nEncryption side: generate the encryption key");
            byte[] encryptedKey = pqcNtruEncryptKey(publicKeyLoad, keyToEncrypt);
            System.out.println("encrypted key length: " + encryptedKey.length
                    + " key: " + bytesToHex(encryptedKey));
            encryptedKeyLength[i] = encryptedKey.length;

            System.out.println("\nDecryption side: receive the encrypted key and decrypt it to the decryption key");
            byte[] decryptedKey = pqcNtruDecryptKey(privateKeyLoad, encryptedKey);
            System.out.println("decryption key length: " + decryptedKey.length + " key: " + bytesToHex(decryptedKey));
            boolean keysAreEqual = Arrays.areEqual(keyToEncrypt, decryptedKey);
            System.out.println("decrypted key is equal to keyToEncrypt: " + keysAreEqual);
            encryptionKeysEquals[i] = keysAreEqual;
        }

        System.out.println("\nTest results");
        System.out.println("parameter spec name  priKL   pubKL encKL  keyE");
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfSpecs; i++) {
             System.out.format("%-20s%6d%8d%6d%6b%n", parameterSpecName[i], privateKeyLength[i], publicKeyLength[i], encryptedKeyLength[i], encryptionKeysEquals[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Legend: priKL privateKey length, pubKL publicKey length, encKL encryption key length, keyE encryption keys are equal\n");
    }

    private static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair generateNtruKeyPair(NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters) {
        NTRUEncryptionKeyPairGenerator ntruEncryptionKeyPairGenerator = new NTRUEncryptionKeyPairGenerator();
        ntruEncryptionKeyPairGenerator.init(ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters);
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair kp = ntruEncryptionKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        return kp;
    }

    private static byte[] pqcNtruEncryptKey(AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey, byte[] keyToEncrypt) {
        NTRUEngine ntru = new NTRUEngine();
        ntru.init(true, publicKey);
        try {
            return ntru.processBlock(keyToEncrypt, 0, keyToEncrypt.length);
        } catch (InvalidCipherTextException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static byte[] pqcNtruDecryptKey(AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey, byte[] encryptedKeyToDecrypt) {
        NTRUEngine ntru = new NTRUEngine();
        ntru.init(false, privateKey);
        try {
            return ntru.processBlock(encryptedKeyToDecrypt, 0, encryptedKeyToDecrypt.length);
        } catch (InvalidCipherTextException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static SecretKeyWithEncapsulation pqcGenerateNtruEncryptionKey(PublicKey publicKey) {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = null;
        try {
            keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Frodo", "BCPQC");
            keyGen.init(new KEMGenerateSpec((PublicKey) publicKey, "AES"), new SecureRandom());
            SecretKeyWithEncapsulation secEnc1 = (SecretKeyWithEncapsulation) keyGen.generateKey();
            return secEnc1;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] pqcGenerateFrodoDecryptionKey(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] encapsulatedKey) {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = null;
        try {
            keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Frodo", "BCPQC");
            keyGen.init(new KEMExtractSpec((PrivateKey) privateKey, encapsulatedKey, "AES"), new SecureRandom());
            SecretKeyWithEncapsulation secEnc2 = (SecretKeyWithEncapsulation) keyGen.generateKey();
            return secEnc2.getEncoded();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static NTRUEncryptionPrivateKeyParameters getNtruPrivateKeyFromEncoded(byte[] encodedKey, NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters) {
        NTRUEncryptionParameters ntruEncryptionParameters = ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters.getEncryptionParameters();
        try {
            return new NTRUEncryptionPrivateKeyParameters(encodedKey, ntruEncryptionParameters);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static NTRUEncryptionPublicKeyParameters getNtruPublicKeyFromEncoded(byte[] encodedKey, NTRUEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters) {
        NTRUEncryptionParameters ntruEncryptionParameters = ntruEncryptionKeyGenerationParameters.getEncryptionParameters();
        return new NTRUEncryptionPublicKeyParameters(encodedKey, ntruEncryptionParameters);
    }

    private static PublicKey getFrodoPublicKeyFromEncoded(byte[] encodedKey) {
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = null;
        try {
            keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("Frodo", "BCPQC");
            return keyFactory.generatePublic(x509EncodedKeySpec);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```